# Report custom summary formulas

Tags: reporting

I have some doubts. Below is my requirement

Custom Objects: Order and Line Item
Requirement: Create a report
Fields to be displayed in the report
Order Name , Client Name, Type, Price, Total Volume , Volume received, Volume Remaining
I can get the Order Name, Client Name,Type,Price,Total Volume from the Order object.

Volume received is the count of all line items with status from new to delivery(Status is from line item object) - How i do i get the count of child records based on status? since the relationship is lookup i cannot go for rollup summary. second thing, Is the custom summary formula row count satisfies this? Can i achieve this using custom summary formula or custom formula field?

Volume Remaining = Total Volume - Volume Received. If volume received is a  custom summary formula , then how do i refer the formula here for this requirement?

Please help me if i am missing anything or what i am doing is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best option here is to use a trigger to rollup the line items and have the formula on the order itself. There is also rollup helper on the [app exchange](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009i3UpEAI) if writing a trigger is not an option.
You could create a formula to be checked on the line item object but that would only help you summarize the total used and not the difference from the total volume.

Answer (score 0):

+1 Jenny

You can also certainly do this with a tigger

This is a great starting place
http://andyinthecloud.com/2014/04/09/new-declarative-rollup-tool-release-community-powered/

There are also a few apps on the AppExchange which do similar.

Last option, you could build it out using flow and flow triggers escaping code and apps all together.